# Windows - Batch file, how to loop or repeat subroutine?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file

I want 13 folders:  One main folder "Folder_A" and twelve other sub-folders for the twelve months (it's a finance thing).  My batch file code assigns Folder_A attributes.  I want these attributes to repeat for the other twelve files.  How to do this in a loop? Right now, I only know to copy-paste twelve times and change folder names, omg, but I need to do this for many other folders A, B, C, D, etc... How to assign/set folder attributes repeating to the twelve sub-folders?

CreateFolders.bat

```
@ECHO OFF  

PUSHD "%~dp0"  
MKDIR "Folder_A"  
ATTRIB +S "Folder_A"  
ATTRIB -R "Folder_A"  
ATTRIB -H -R "Folder_A\BLUEA.ini.ico"  
ATTRIB -H -R "Folder_A\Desktop.ini"  
COPY /Y "BLUEA.ini.ico" "Folder_A\BLUEA.ini.ico"  
ECHO [.ShellClassInfo] > "Folder_A\Desktop.ini"  
ECHO IconFile=BLUEA.ini.ico >> "Folder_A\Desktop.ini"  
ECHO IconIndex=0 >> "Folder_A\Desktop.ini"  
ECHO InfoTip=Apples Apples Apples >> "Folder_A\Desktop.ini"  
ATTRIB +H +R "Folder_A\BLUEA.ini.ico"  
ATTRIB +H +R "Folder_A\Desktop.ini"  
ATTRIB +R "Folder_A"  
POPD  

MD Folder_A\2019_01
MD Folder_A\2019_02
MD Folder_A\2019_03
MD Folder_A\2019_04
MD Folder_A\2019_05
MD Folder_A\2019_06
MD Folder_A\2019_07
MD Folder_A\2019_08
MD Folder_A\2019_09
MD Folder_A\2019_10
MD Folder_A\2019_11
MD Folder_A\2019_12

EXIT
```

Comment: [For - Loop through a range of numbers - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/for_l.html)

Comment: To have a leading zero with month 1-9 you either need 2 `for /l` or you use a simple `for %%M in (01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12) do md "Folder_A\2019_%%M"` BTW the `POPD` should be after the MDs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the folder icons should change with your letters, 
this batch with nested for and (code blocks) might do:

```
:: A:\Test\SU_1442422.cmd
@ECHO OFF  

PUSHD "%~dp0"
For %%F in (A B C D) Do (
    MKDIR "Folder_%%F"  
    ATTRIB    -R "Folder_%%F"  
    ATTRIB -H -R "Folder_%%F\BLUE%%F.ini.ico"  
    ATTRIB -H -R "Folder_%%F\Desktop.ini"  
    COPY /Y "BLUE%%F.ini.ico" "Folder_%%F\"  

    ( ECHO [.ShellClassInfo]  
      ECHO IconFile=BLUE%%F.ini.ico
      ECHO IconIndex=0
      ECHO InfoTip=Apples Apples Apples
    ) > "Folder_%%F\Desktop.ini"

    for %%M in (01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12) do (
        MKDIR     "Folder_%%F\2019_%%M"
        ATTRIB +R "Folder_%%F\2019_%%M"
    )

    ATTRIB +H +R "Folder_%%F\BLUE%%F.ini.ico"  
    ATTRIB +H +R "Folder_%%F\Desktop.ini"  
    ATTRIB +S +R "Folder_%%F"  
)
POPD
```

[image]

Comment: OMG, this is so awesome!!  Thank you LolPings!!!

Comment: Sorry LotPings... misspelled your alias above....  I want to learn more DOS commands!!

Comment: Never mind, you can always delete your comments ;-) BTW [The Windows command prompt is NOT a DOS prompt!](https://scalibq.wordpress.com/2012/05/23/the-windows-command-prompt-is-not-a-dos-prompt/)

Comment: Hi LotPings... Quick question... For the above code, I would like to make the root directory (such as "C:\" a variable, so that I can do this for C:\ and D:\ and E:\ and F:\  etc.... How to do adjust the code above to do this?

Comment: The batch takes it's own location as the base, so simply copy/move it (and the icon files) where you want the folders to be created.